# OnClick Databinding not working in android

Tags: android, data-binding

i have this class user

[image: Class User]

and i'm trying to implement the onClick binding in android i also have this Presenter Class

[image: Presenter Class]

Im initializing my binding like this 
[image]

Also in my XML file

[image]

I'm setting my variables but i'm getting this error when compiling 
[image]

Comment: Did u configure gradle file for databinding?

Comment: User.adress is observablestring not a string. change parameter type accordingly

Comment: i've changed it to Observable<String> and it's not working no it's showing 
Error:(37, 39) cannot find method onSaveClick(java.lang.String) in class com.example.alternative.mytest.Presenter 

even that i implemented like this : 
  public void onSaveClick(ObservableField<String>  task)
and :
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> presenter.onSaveClick(user.address)}"

Comment: i think there is a problem with the DataBinding Lib it self since i've tried with parameter String directly and it works , but what i need is just passing the ObservableField , i think DataBinding lib Recognized it as a String not ObservableField<String>

Comment: This appears to be a bug in data binding itself. It should not barf on you like that. Can you try your project out with Android Studio 2.4 preview and see if it gives you the same error? This is a useful data point to see if the bug has already been fixed. It appears that the code has changed there to fix this bug. If it has not been fixed can you file a bug for it and attach a project that demonstrates it? Thanks!

Comment: Please add code and errors as **text** ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors in text format are much better than code/errors as an image, which are better than nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error.

Comment: As @Makyen indicated, images of code aren't allowed here. Please just post it as text.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a `View` by parameter and your method in `Presenter` class is not receiving it. 
To fix this issue, change your method to this:

```
 public class Presenter{
        public void onSaveClick(View view, String task){
            Log.i("log", "Action" + task)
        }
```

And then, pass it in your xml:

```
android:onClick="@{(v) -> presenter.onSaveClick(v, user.address)}"
```

Comment: Not solving the issue it still the same, why passing that extra view param i don't need it.

Comment: I'm sorry. I edit my answer. check now.

Comment: you need to pass it because the onClick handler has a view in your signature.

Comment: i've tried it also like this and it's not working , 
i did a change i only passed v as parameter and it working after i changed my Method 
to: public void onSaveClick(View view)
and @{(v) -> presenter.onSaveClick(v)

but i need the second parameter, how can i do it with two parameters

Comment: you have to change the type of address field to a String. Not Observable

Comment: Correct it should be ObservablField but it's not solving it by changing the parameter Type.

Answer (score 0):

Either change xml

`android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.onSaveClick(user.address.get ())}"`

Or presenter

```
onSaveClick (ObservableField<String> address){

Log.d ("log", address.get ())
}
```

Comment: changing to android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.onSaveClick(user.address.get())}"
and :
    public void onSaveClick(String task){
, getting this Error :  cannot find method get() in class java.lang.String

Comment: Add  <import type="android.databinding.ObservableField"/> inside data tag in the layout xml and try again

Comment: 2nd option must also work

Answer (score 0):

User Model:

```
private ObservableField<String> address = new ObservableField<>();

public String getAddress() {
    return address.get();
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address.set(address);
}
```

Xml:

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@{user.address}"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
       android:onClick="@{(v) -> event.onSaveCLick(user.address)}"/>
```

Java:

```
public class Presenter{
        public void onSaveCLick(String task){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Address"+task,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because your referencing the presenter incorrectly!.The error is saying you typed in the wrong package when setting variables in XML. It actually has nothing to do with the android:onClick, but the fact that your referencing the presenter, without binding it. In your activity after you set your presenter you have to do mainBinding.setVariable(BR.presenter, presenter); .It should work just fine after that.